# Angular router-outlet breaking mat-grid-list

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-router

I'm trying to create a very simple SPA with a top toolbar and some content.

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|               mat-toolbar                 |
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|              router-outlet                |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

I want the `<router-outlet>` to fill the remaing space. The `<router-outlet>` will contain a custom component `<app-dashboard>` divided in two columns each taking 1/3 and 2/3 of the available space.

I'm trying to achieve this with `<mat-grid-list>` but it breaks. Here's what I got so far (`<app-business>` and `<app-reservations>` are simply filled with lorem ipsum):

dashboard.component.html

```html
<mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="fit">
    <mat-grid-tile>
        <app-business></app-business>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="2">
        <app-reservations></app-reservations>
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

app.component.html

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <span>{{title}}</span>
  <span class="spacer"></span>
  <button mat-icon-button aria-label="Logout" title="Logout">
    <mat-icon>logout</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-toolbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Any hint is much appreciated.

### Edit

Here's a StackBlitz showing my setup: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bnkf7o

Answer (score 0):

Set CSS to mat-grid-tile

```
 mat-grid-tile 
   {
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin-top: 5px;
    overflow: scroll;
    }
```

Here is updated URL.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yuwmvu?embed=1&file=src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.css

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at it, but this not what I'm looking for (though it's close). What I'm trying to achieve is a non-scroll page (but inner content only). Plus, in your StackBlitz the content gets cut.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing the grid manually with CSS. It wasn't fun and I don't like the solution, but since there seems to be no other way...

app.component.html

```html
<div class="container">
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <span>{{title}}</span>
    <span class="spacer"></span>
    <button mat-icon-button aria-label="Logout" title="Logout">
      <mat-icon>logout</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-toolbar>
  <div class="content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.component.css

```css
.spacer {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

mat-toolbar {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    min-height: 0;
}
```

dashboard.component.html

```html
<div class="container">
    <app-business></app-business>
    <app-reservations></app-reservations>
</div>
```

dashboard.component.css

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}

app-business {
    flex: 1 1 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

app-reservations {
    flex: 2 1 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I've also forked the StackBlitz with the solution, but it doesn't show the correct result (guess it's because of the fake browser window). Consider downloading it and running it locally if needed: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jdgsfx